# Code not showing record from other table

Tags: php, mysql

I created a detail page where I can filter persons by the filled in value how ever my table is not showing address and cv information. Those two are in seperate tables so I have address table and cv(a pdf file) table with their own values.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
$valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];
// search in all table columns
// using concat mysql function
$query = "SELECT person_id, person_firstname, person_lastname, 
             person_email, person_phonenumber,  
             address_street,address_housenumber, 
             address_city,address_state,address_zipcode,cv_path
      FROM person 
        inner join address on address.address_id = person.person_address 
        inner join cv on cv.cv_id = person.person_cv 
          WHERE CONCAT(`person_firstname`, `person_lastname`, `address_street`, `address_housenumber`, `address_zipcode`, `address_city`, `address_state`, `person_email`, `person_phonenumber` ) 
          LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";
$search_result = filterTable($query);

}
else {
$query = "SELECT * FROM `person`";
$search_result = filterTable($query);
}

// function to connect and execute the query
function filterTable($query)
{
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "usbw", "persons");
$filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
return $filter_Result;
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PHP HTML TABLE DATA SEARCH</title>
    <style>
        table,tr,th,td
        {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="testing.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="valueToSearch" placeholder="Value To Search"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="search" value="Filter"><br><br>

        <table>
             <tr>
                <th>Voornaam</th>
                <th>Achternaam</th>
                <th>Straat</th>
                <th>Huisnummer</th>
                <th>Postcode</th>
                <th>Stad</th>
                <th>Provincie</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Mobiel</th>
                <th>cv</th>
                <th>delete</th>
            </tr>;

  <!-- populate table from mysql database -->
            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['person_firstname'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['person_lastname'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['address_street'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['address_housenumber'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['address_zipcode'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['address_city'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['address_state'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['person_email'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['person_phonenumber'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo "<a href='http://localhost:8080/website/" . $row['cv_path'] . "'>cv file</a>";?></td>
                <td><?php echo "<a href='delete.php?person_id=" . $row['person_id'] . "'>delete</a>";?></td>

            </tr>
            <?php endwhile;?>
        </table>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

The strange thing of this all is when I go to the page it shows me a error: Notice: Undefined index: address_street in D:\Server\root\Website\testing.php on line xx ( for all address and cv fiels). BUT when I filter something it will show everything like it should be so address and cv is showing.

UPDATE:

[image: 1]

UPDATE2:
Delete.php:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "usbw";
$dbname = "persons";

// CREATE A CONNECTION WITH THE DATABASE
// CONNECTIE MAKEN MET DATABASE
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// GET ID FROM person_id
// PAK ID VAN person_id 
$id=$_GET['person_id']; 

// CREATE PREPARE STATMENT FOR DELETING RECORDS FROM person_id
// MAAK EEN STATEMENT OM WAARDES TE VERWIJDEREN VAN person_id
$stmt = $conn->prepare('DELETE FROM person WHERE person_id = ?'); 
$stmt->bind_param('s', $id);                                         

// EXECUTE STATEMENT AND IF RESULT IS FALSE SHOW ERROR
// VOER STATEMENT UIT EN ALS VALS IS GEEF ERROR AAN
$result = $stmt->execute();    
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die("Error: " . $stmt->error);
}
// AFTER CLICKING DELETE GO TO LINK
// NA HET DRUKKEN VAN DELETE GA NAAR LINK
header("Location: http://localhost:8080/Website/admin.php");

// CLOSE CONNECTION AND STATEMENT
// SLUIT CONNECTIE EN STATEMENT
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Where are  your `on` clauses of the joins?

Comment: oops! wait one min I do have other select code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is probably caused because when you enter the page, you are not submitting `$_POST["search"]` and therefore script enters `else` branch that selects only data from table `person` which by all the evidence **does not** contain column `street_address`.

You are then trying to print it out anyway, which is where undefined index issue occurs.

---

**EDIT**: As the topic progressed, OP bumped into another problem - when he deletes record from person, there are remaining records in tables `cv` and `address`.

In fact you need to execute three `DELETE` sql queries in total. Not one.

First of all, you have to identify records in `cv` table and `address` table and delete them, then you delete the person record:

```
DELETE FROM address WHERE address_id='$addressIDForPerson'
```

Where `$addressIDForPerson` is value of `person_address` column in record from `person` table that you are trying to delete.

Second step would be to remove the record from `cv` table, again identified by value of column in `person` table.

```
DELETE FROM cv WHERE cv_id='$cvIDForPerson'
```

Where $cvIDForPerson is value of `person_cv` column in record from `cv` table that you are trying to delete.

And finally, you delete the recordf rom person

```
DELETE FROM person WHERE person_id=`$personID`
```

Where `$personID` identifies the person you are trying to delete.

Comment: So if I put `$query = "SELECT * FROM person INNER JOIN address INNER JOIN cv";` it should work?

Comment: @GLRotterdam I do not know how your tables `person` and `address` really look like. What you need to do is to get all the data you display even in `else` branch. TL;DR: You need to join it, but without knowledge of your tables I can not tell you how exactly.

Comment: I try to explain because I am having one other problem as you can see in update: It is showing data lots of times but in my database there is just one record.

I have three tables called person, address and cv address_id is linked to my person_address and cv_id is linked to my person_cv so every table has a relation with eachother. How ever I see I do have one more problem when pressing delete it will ONLY delete person records and NOT address and cv record...

Comment: @GLRotterdam First of all: I suppose you really should join it as you proposed in first comment under this answer. With using `on` parts in the `join` - it is working for the filtering, it should work even here.
As it goes for `delete`, I will update answer.

Comment: Alright it isn't showing double data anymore that's great! Look at update I added my delete.php I am using INNODB with on delete cascade for address_id and cv_id.

Answer (score 0):

In your query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `person` 
LEFT JOIN `address` 
LEFT JOIN `cv` 
WHERE CONCAT(`person_firstname`, `person_lastname`, `address_street`, `address_housenumber`, `address_zipcode`, `address_city`, `address_state`, `person_email`, `person_phonenumber` ) LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";
```

I do not see any ON clause for the JOINS.

You should put those clauses.